# I have installed tensorflow but still facing error on importing tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7.3 on PyCharm IDE and did a pip install of of Tensorflow using command prompt(since install from IDE didn't work)as below

pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.13.1-py3-none-any.whl

Tensorflow got installed successfully and is showing in my IDE interpreter

Now, when a run a code that just has "import tensorflow" I'm getting Falied to load native tensor flow runtime error

Error message:

```py
E:\ImageClassification\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "E:\Python\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', [dirname(__file__)])
  File "E:\Python\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --upgrade tensorflow`

or

you can uninstall the tensorflow and re-install it.